# Add Fragment before and after current position in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` which contains `Fragments`. I want to add fragment before and after the current position. Here is the adapter:

```
public class TabManager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof  Fragment) {
            return list.indexOf(object);
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int index) {
        list.add(index, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

I can add fragments after my position (it appears in the right side of the ViewPager) without problem. But if I add a new fragment before my position (the left side of the ViewPager) the ViewPager immediately focuses to it.

So, my question is, how to add a new fragment to the left side, without focusing (so let the user swipe) to it?

In other words here is one fragment:

```
1

^
```

I add a new one to the right side, but the first one stay focusing:

```
1 2

^
```

Now, if I add another one to the left side it immediately focuses (that's what I don't want):

```
3 1 2

^
```

This should be the correct:

```
3 1 2

  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can not comment due to a reputation.
If  your current position is **0 (1 fragment)**, and you add fragment to the right side, current item position dos not change - **0** (added fragment does not change it).

But if you add the fragment to the left side (before fragment **1**), your adapter's current position still **0**, and the fragment on that position is now **fragment 3**, NOT **fragment 0** anymore. So i guess before notifying adapter you should change your adapter's position to the desired item (if you add after - do nothing, if you add before - correct you position).
In you case - set current adapter position to 1 instead of 0.